# The Templar follower and the Paladin from Diablo 2, any relation?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Templar follow you get in act one is of course a part of some religious Order. So is the playable Paladin in Diablo 2. Is there any know tie due to an organization? Are they a part of the game group or religion?

Comment: If you just want to look at the fact it is a Blizzard game there likely is a connection.  Of course does not change the parallels between the two orders.  Blizzard likes to place small sections of their other IPs into their games.  So it would not shock if if the Templar was choosen because they wanted to do exactly that but with a twist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though the Templar Order is **not** the same as the Paladins of Zakarum or their splintered Order of Paladins, there are interesting parallels between them -

- Kormac himself was previously a promising soldier of Westmarch before 'joining' the Templars, suggesting activity in the old haunts of the Paladins, likely linked to the fact that..
- .. the Templar Order seeks scrolls stolen long ago by Archbishop Lazarus of the Zakarum Church..
- .. and both orders seem to have some deep-seated issues with betrayal within and without, and supernatural beings trying to manipulate them.